# What is a proper way to connect to a sqlite database, execute a prepared Statement and close the connection with java?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

This is my code at the moment. I have or had several problems:

- Database is busy - error
- SQL error or missing database
- Resultset closed

Which code structure should I use if I want to prevent both of these errors?
Do I need to connect in the try block? Where do I need to close the connection? Where do I need to close the preparedStatement?

I was not able to find a solution by connecting the information of different pages by myself until now.

```
    public boolean checkForUser(String username){
        try(Connection con = this.connect();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = createPreparedStatementRegistrate(conn, username);
                ResultSet rs= pstmt.executeQuery();)
                {
                if (rueck.next()){
                    pstmt.close();
                    rs.close();
                    con.close();
                    //do some stuff
                }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

---

```
private PreparedStatement createPreparedStatementRegistrate(Connection conn, String username) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1, username);
    return pstmt;
}
```

---

```
private Connection connect() {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:user.db";
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
```

---

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.checkOpen(CoreResultSet.java:69)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.findColumn(JDBC3ResultSet.java:38)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getString(JDBC3ResultSet.java:443)
    at zugriffsverwaltung.Zugriffsverwaltung.loeschen(Zugriffsverwaltung.java:215)
    at zugriffsverwaltung.Zugriffsverwaltung.<init>(Zugriffsverwaltung.java:37)
    at main.Server.<init>(Server.java:29)
    at main.Server.main(Server.java:46)
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.internalClose(CoreStatement.java:115)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.close(JDBC3Statement.java:35)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Statement.close(JDBC4Statement.java:27)
    at zugriffsverwaltung.Zugriffsverwaltung.loeschen(Zugriffsverwaltung.java:238)
    at zugriffsverwaltung.Zugriffsverwaltung.<init>(Zugriffsverwaltung.java:37)
    at main.Server.<init>(Server.java:29)
    at main.Server.main(Server.java:46)
```

Comment: You should be more specific about the errors you get (post the stacktrace and explain **when** and **where** you get the error).

Comment: I generalized my code a bit. Now I added a stacktrace of code which has the same structure.

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't match the code (`checkForUser` vs `loeschen`), the stacktrace contains a `getString` not present in your code, etc, but I have written an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are closing the result set, statement and connection before you do things with the result set. This is not allowed: a result set needs to be open when you retrieve values using `getString` (not shown in your code, but present in your stack trace).

As you are using try-with-resource which will close the resource on exit, it is even unnecessary to explicitly close. It also looks like the SQLite driver does not meet the JDBC requirements that closing an already closed resource should be a no-op, as it is throwing an exception that the connection is closed when closing the statement (likely by the try-with-resources).

You need to change your code to

```
public boolean checkForUser(String username){
    try(Connection con = this.connect();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = createPreparedStatementRegistrate(conn, username);
            ResultSet rs= pstmt.executeQuery();)
            {
            if (rueck.next()){
                //do some stuff
            }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

That is, remove the lines

```
pstmt.close();
rs.close();
con.close();
```